# How to create 1D array from 2D array or multi array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => RANO17
        [1] => RANO99
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Test Product Ranosys
        [1] => Rano test example
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 200.0000
        [1] => 100.0000
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1400
        [1] => 200
    )

)
```

I want to make 1D array from above array. 1D array looks like.

```
Array(
[0] => Array
(
  [0] => RANO17
  [1] => Test Product Ranosys
  [2] => 7
  [3] => 
  [4] => 200.0000
  [5] => 
  [6] => 1400
)

[1] =>Array 
(
  [0] => RANO99
  [1] => Rano test example
  [2] => 2
  [3] => 
  [4] => 100.0000
  [5] => 
  [6] => 200
)
)
```

I don't have any idea how can we do this I was googling from last two hours but didn't get any solution yet. How can we do this either using some array functions or any programming logic please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything, so far? If not, look into [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) or [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). There aren't any existing functions that will do exactly what you want, out of the box..

Comment: yes I do but I am getting only one array.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => RANO17
    [1] => Test Product Ranosys
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 
    [4] => 200.0000
    [5] => 
    [6] => 1400
)

Comment: Is this 1d array or two 1d arrays ?

Comment: It is 1d array @VforVendetta

Comment: I don't think it is only one 1d array. Your output is showing two 1d arrays.

Comment: I didn't mentioned array keys for this single array that's why you are thinking so.

Comment: Although I have solved It you can see below @ V for Vandetta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. It will work if multiarray has dynamic values.
**output of $orders_rows**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [0] => RANO17
    [1] => RANO99
  )

 [1] => Array
 (
    [0] => Test Product Ranosys
    [1] => Rano test example
 )

 [2] => Array
 (
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 2
 )

 [3] => Array
 (
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
 )

 [4] => Array
 (
    [0] => 200.0000
    [1] => 100.0000
 )

 [5] => Array
 (
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
 )

 [6] => Array
 (
    [0] => 1400
    [1] => 200
 )

)
```

There's code to solve my problem

```
foreach ($orders_rows as $singlerows) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($singlerows[0]); $k++) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($singlerows); $i++) {
                $output_array[] = $singlerows[$i][$k];
            }
        }
    }
    $orders_row = array_chunk($output_array, 7);
```

**output of $orders_row**

```
Array
(
  [0] => RANO17
  [1] => Test Product Ranosys
  [2] => 7
  [3] => 
  [4] => 200.0000
  [5] => 
  [6] => 1400
)
Array
(
  [0] => RANO99
  [1] => Rano test example
  [2] => 2
  [3] => 
  [4] => 100.0000
  [5] => 
  [6] => 200
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$newArr1 = array();
$newArr2 = array();

foreach ( $arr AS $element ) {
  $newArr1[] = $element[ 0 ];
  $newArr2[] = $element[ 1 ];
}
```

Comment: Your second code block won't do what you think. `$newArr[ $i ]` will always only contain `$element[ 1 ]`.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Ben but what will be the solution if I have dynamic values in multiarray ?

Comment: @Ramkishan - You need to specify those things in your question. The first code block does do what you want when using your example data. If it can look different, you need to specify how. Don't move the goalpost.

Comment: sorry @MagnusEriksson one minute I update the question

Comment: @Ramkishan - You should rather apologize to the people that have wasted time by answering your inaccurate question. You should keep this question as is, mark an answer and write a new question with _all_ the details instead.

Comment: yes you are right @MagnusEriksson It was my mistake sorry again.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson for pointing out the mistake in the second code block. I have corrected it so that the first reference to $newArr in the loop adds an element to the array.

Comment: @Ramkishan Did you reposted the question referencing "dynamic values"? If so, please post a link.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through the array and dump the element of each array into separate arrays.

```
$myArray = array (array(1, "testing 1"), array(2, "testing 2"), array(3, "testing 3"));

$arrayOne = array();
$arrayTwo = array();
```

For each element of the main array, echo the two elements of the sub array into separate arrays of their own.

```
foreach ($myArray as $a) {
    $arrayOne[] = $a[0];
    $arrayTwo[] = $a[1];
}
```

print the results

```
print_r($arrayOne);
echo "\n\n";
print_r($arrayTwo);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)


Array
(
    [0] => testing 1
    [1] => testing 2
    [2] => testing 3
)
```